# Query referenced XML-Element with Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, symfony, soap, xpath

i'm using the BeSimpleSoapBundle to generate a webservice in Symfony 2. 
The Response of the retrieveOrders method is supposed to be used within a workflow engine.

The generated response of the webservice is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="..." xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:retrieveOrdersResponse>
  <return>
    <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <lieferdatum>2013-07-03T10:53:38+00:00</lieferdatum>
      <tatsaechlichesLieferdatum xsi:nil="true" />
      <bestellpositionen />
    </item>
    <item id="ref1">
      <id>10</id>
      <lieferdatum>2013-07-03T10:53:38+00:00</lieferdatum>
      <tatsaechlichesLieferdatum xsi:nil="true" />
      <bestellpositionen>
        <item>
          <id>6</id>
          <liefermenge>3</liefermenge>
          <bestellung href="#ref1" />
          <produkt id="ref3">
            <id>1</id>
            <bezeichnung>test</bezeichnung>
          </produkt>
          <abweichungen />
        </item>
      </bestellpositionen>
    </item>
    <item id="ref2">
      <id>11</id>
      <lieferdatum>2013-07-03T10:53:38+00:00</lieferdatum>
      <tatsaechlichesLieferdatum xsi:nil="true" />
      <bestellpositionen>
        <item>
          <id>7</id>
          <liefermenge>3</liefermenge>
          <bestellung href="#ref2" />
          <produkt href="#ref3" />
          <abweichungen />
        </item>
      </bestellpositionen>
    </item>
    <item id="ref4">
      <id>12</id>
      <lieferdatum>2013-07-03T10:53:38+00:00</lieferdatum>
      <tatsaechlichesLieferdatum xsi:nil="true" />
      <bestellpositionen>
        <item>
          <id>8</id>
          <liefermenge>3</liefermenge>
          <bestellung href="#ref4" />
          <produkt href="#ref3" />
          <abweichungen />
        </item>
      </bestellpositionen>
    </item>
    <item id="ref5">
      <id>13</id>
      <lieferdatum>2013-07-03T10:53:38+00:00</lieferdatum>
      <tatsaechlichesLieferdatum xsi:nil="true" />
      <bestellpositionen>
        <item>
          <id>9</id>
          <liefermenge>3</liefermenge>
          <bestellung href="#ref5" />
          <produkt href="#ref3" />
          <abweichungen />
        </item>
      </bestellpositionen>
    </item>
    <item id="ref6">
      <id>14</id>
      <lieferdatum>2013-07-03T10:53:38+00:00</lieferdatum>
      <tatsaechlichesLieferdatum xsi:nil="true" />
      <bestellpositionen>
        <item>
          <id>10</id>
          <liefermenge>3</liefermenge>
          <bestellung href="#ref6" />
          <produkt href="#ref3" />
          <abweichungen />
        </item>
      </bestellpositionen>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>15</id>
      <lieferdatum>2013-12-07T07:00:00+00:00</lieferdatum>
      <tatsaechlichesLieferdatum xsi:nil="true" />
      <bestellpositionen />
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>16</id>
      <lieferdatum>2013-12-07T07:00:00+00:00</lieferdatum>
      <tatsaechlichesLieferdatum xsi:nil="true" />
      <bestellpositionen />
    </item>
    <item id="ref7">
      <id>17</id>
      <lieferdatum>2013-12-07T07:00:00+00:00</lieferdatum>
      <tatsaechlichesLieferdatum xsi:nil="true" />
      <bestellpositionen>
        <item>
          <id>11</id>
          <liefermenge>2</liefermenge>
          <bestellung href="#ref7" />
          <produkt href="#ref3" />
          <abweichungen />
        </item>
      </bestellpositionen>
    </item>
    <item id="ref8">
      <id>18</id>
      <lieferdatum>2013-12-17T07:00:00+00:00</lieferdatum>
      <tatsaechlichesLieferdatum xsi:nil="true" />
      <bestellpositionen>
        <item>
          <id>12</id>
          <liefermenge>2</liefermenge>
          <bestellung href="#ref8" />
          <produkt href="#ref3" />
          <abweichungen />
        </item>
      </bestellpositionen>
    </item>
  </return>
</ns1:retrieveOrdersResponse>
```

As you can see, the BeSimpleSoapBundle has generated links to XML-Elements that have been outputted before.

Instead of defining the product #ref3 again, it is referenced by `<produkt href="#ref3" />`.

But how can I access the properties/nodes of a references element via Xpath?
In concrete: How do I get the first products name ('bezeichnung')?

The following Xpath query is not working:

```
/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns1:retrieveOrdersResponse/return/item[id=18]/bestellpositionen/item[id=12]/produkt/bezeichnung
```

My questions are:

- Why it's not working?
- Are these references standardized?
- If it's not working with Xpath, is there a simple way to resolve the structure with XSLT?
- Is there a way to prevent this default bevaiour in the BeSimpleSoapBundle?

Thank you in advance!

**Update**

A friend of mine has told me that there is an If-then-else construct, which allows to me
to resolve the structure like this:

```
(if(orders/item[id=18]/bestellpositionen/item[id=12]/produkt/@href) 
then(orders/item/bestellpositionen/item/produkt[@id= fn:substring(/orders/item[id=18]    /bestellpositionen/item[id=12]/produkt/@href, 2) ]) 
else (orders/item[id=18]/bestellpositionen/item[id=12]/produkt))/bezeichnung
```

It works, though it's not perfect. If there is a dedicated function that simplifies that logic, please let me know!

Comment: Try this `//bezeichnung`

Comment: unfortunately the same effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XPath like this should work:

```
orders/item[id = 18]/bestellpositionen/item[id = 12]/produkt/bezeichnung | 
orders/item/bestellpositionen/item/produkt[id = 
   substring-after(../../../../item[id = 18]/bestellpositionen/item[id = 12]
                              /produkt/@href, '#')]
```

One other thing you could do is to use this simple XSLT to resolve all the references:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="kRefTarget" match="*[@id]" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- The [not(substring-after(@href, '#') = ancestor::*/@id)] portion prevents 
       infinite recursion on <bestellung> and anything else that references its
       own ancestor. -->
  <xsl:template match="*[@href]
                        [not(substring-after(@href, '#') = ancestor::*/@id)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kRefTarget', substring-after(@href, '#'))" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After running this on your sample input, the XML for item 18 looks like:

```
<item id="ref8">
  <id>18</id>
  <lieferdatum>2013-12-17T07:00:00+00:00</lieferdatum>
  <tatsaechlichesLieferdatum xsi:nil="true" />
  <bestellpositionen>
    <item>
      <id>12</id>
      <liefermenge>2</liefermenge>
      <bestellung href="#ref8" />
      <produkt id="ref3">
        <id>1</id>
        <bezeichnung>test</bezeichnung>
      </produkt>
      <abweichungen />
    </item>
  </bestellpositionen>
</item>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works fine. The transformation hels a lot, when doing a lot of queries.

Comment: @twiechert Glad to hear that. If this solves your question, I'd be thankful if you can mark this as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark icon. :)